# how to build playorm JARs

Tags: gradle, playorm

I am new to playorm and gradle. My goal is to get playorm compiled (especially play 2.1 plugin) and deployed to local nexus repository manager.

What gradle tasks should I invoke to do this?

I tried to run *gradlew clean assemble* - creates workspace*.jar in *output/libs* so I assume build part was done. How to get these artefacts renamed and uploaded to my nexus?

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm

Comment: Please note that the Play2.1 plugin's source files are not part of Playorm's core as Playorm support both Play1.2.x and Play2 frameworks and that is why only the jar is included explicitly.

Comment: Vikas( @Easility ), he is talking about binaries not source files.  ie. he just wants to compile the playorm code with the playorm plugin for playframework 2.1 and put that in his local repository.  Can you feed him the steps for just that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created *local.gradle* and included it in *build.gradle* to create *uploadArchives* task using standard gradle upload procedure.

build.gradle was modified in upstream version to include local.gradle if exists.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read [this chapter](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) of the user guide. It looks like the only repository configured for playorm is Maven Central, but the user guide tells you how to configure your own repository and interact with it. After following the guide, if you have a more specific question ask again here.